# Passing data from component to component

Tags: angular

I would like to take the data they enter in my password reset form that only has one field that is the mail and that mail you enter the user, call it in another component and if possible hidden with asterisks

I have tried with code fragments but I don't understand very well how to do it with input and ouput and eventmitter in angular.

I share with you the code I have and the image of what I seek to achieve

```
<div class="container-fluid forgot-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12  text-center">

            <div class="logo">
                LOGO
            </div>
            <p class="subtitle">
                Ingresa el correo electrónico registrado en la<br/> plataforma para recuperar tu contraseña.
            </p>
            <form [formGroup]="form">
                <mat-form-field class="inputForm">
                    <input autocomplete="off" matInput placeholder="Correo electrónico" type="email" formControlName="email">
                </mat-form-field>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="!email.valid">
                        {{getEmailError()}}
                    </mat-error>
                <button (click)="goToInstructions();" class="btn-recovery" [disabled]="!form.valid" mat-flat-button >RECUPERAR CONTRASEÑA</button>
            </form>
                <button (click)="goToLogin()" class="btn-back" mat-flat-button >VOLVER</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Forgot password ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'zonasegura-forgot-password',
  templateUrl: './forgot-password.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forgot-password.component.scss']
})
export class ForgotPasswordComponent implements OnInit {
  

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  goToLogin(){
    this.router.navigate(['/log-in'])
  }

  goToInstructions(){
    this.router.navigate(['/password-instruction'])
  }

  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl('', [ Validators.email, Validators.required ])
  });

    get email() { return this.form.get('email'); }

  getEmailError() {
    if (this.email.hasError('email')) {
      return 'Ingrese un correo electronico valido.';
    }
    if (this.email.hasError('required')) {
      return 'Un correo es requerido.';
    }
  }  

}
```

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3BQq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I am understanding you correct you want to gather the value from user email so you can pass that value to another part of the form in a message?

Is is on 2 separate instances of a page(like the image shows)? or you fill out email -> go to next section(Component) with email message in the text?

If it is all in the same page like the image looks create a  2-way data binding event. Store the value and when the email is summited the stored value will appear where ever you  have the it binded to.

```
<form (submit)="onSubmit()">
   <input [(ngModel)]="capturedEmail">
</form>

let capturedEmail: string;
onSubmit() {
  return this.capturedEmail
```

If these are 2 seprate events(meaning components opening up)?

There are sevral ways you can do this the all involve storing the data ether in local storage or 2 way data binding routes, Property decorators such s viewshed (parent and children's)

- user fills out email form
- next component opens with email messaged passed in text

You could just use plain old JavaScript as well if you do not want to store the data and it is for visual effect?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as you say, the idea is that you type the form and then you are redirected to another component example: forgot password redirect to password instruction is it good practice to do it like that? Or it's much better to do it in the same component forgot and text with instructions. 

There is something to keep in mind, and that is that this part of the program is not yet anchored to the back end

Answer (score 0):

Create a container component that acts as a container for the two components:

1. The component containing the form where you enter the email id.
2. The component containing the message showing that password has been emailed to *** email.

There should be a "display" variable in the container component. If the value of display is true, display component 1 and hide component 2. If the value is false, hide component 1 and display component 2. There must be an input parameter in component 2 through which, a variable "emailid" belonging to the container component will be passed from container component to component 2.

Now, as soon as the user types the email id and the form is submitted, emit an output event containing the email id as the emitted value. The emit event call triggers a "toggleDisplay" function of the container component with the emailid as parameter which toggles the value of display and also assigns the value to "emailId". Now, since this emailId value was passed as input to component 2, it will be available to component 2 and can be displayed.

Comment: Thank you for your response, depending on the response from my development leader I will implement your solution based on the other responses received here